# Using earphones to play music while on Hangouts/Messenger video call

Tags: video-chat

I had this issue while video chatting on Google Hangouts with a friend. We were both using earphones. We were trying to play music on our respective computers.

I’m using Windows, she’s using iOS. I’m using Chrome, I’m presuming she uses Safari.

When she played music on hers, it was audible to me too, but when I played it, she couldn't hear any music, she just heard my voice but no audio playing on the computer.

I switched to different earphones, but the issue wasn't resolved, so I’m guessing I should be changing some settings on my computer or for Hangouts.

Anyone have any idea what is happening??

Comment: @fixer1234 They do, but that shouldn't be relevant, I believe. The music on her PC shouldn't have anything to do with her mic, right?

Comment: @fixer1234 But she's using earphones too, and so, the music isn't being played out loud for the mic to pick up.

Comment: OK, good point.

Comment: Are you both using the Chrome browser ? Are you both on Windows?

Comment: @harrymc I’m using windows, she’s using iOS. I’m using Chrome, I’m presuming she uses Safari.

Comment: Can she try Chrome?

Comment: @harrymc She's using Chrome, didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a driver thing.

Some sound cards have drivers that provide "stereo mix" audio input (although names can differ). It's a virtual input that mixes microphone input with speaker output, ie. it streams both what you're saying and what you're hearing. Selecting this as input device would result in the other side hearing the music you're playing.

I assume you're both using Windows. If you have such device, it would appear in Windows' sound settings. In Windows 10 that's right-click on the speaker icon in notification area → *Sounds* → *Recording* tab. You can right-click any listed device to make it the default. Audio/video chat software may also let you override that choice.

Comment: Hi. I tried doing this, didn't help.

Comment: When I switch to Sterro Mix from the Hangouts app, she can hear the music but not my voice.

Comment: @MathManiac That's because mic input is usually not sent by default to the mix output (otherwise you would hear yourself in speakers or headphones). You should unmute the mic in output mixer settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share audio to the respective person on other side you can use software like Virtual Audio Cable. To share stereo Mix and Microphone at same time, only more advanced users may be able to configure this, but you could always google a tutorial.